# transfer spl token from program to user ata

Tags: anchor, spl-token, cpi, spl-token-program

I'm trying to transfer spl token from pda to user but constantly this error occured

```
 Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I checked the seeds is identical with pool_lp_valut but error keep occured.

Comment: Have you tried looking at some of the other answers on here for the error `Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`. Usually this means the account isn't mutable or the seeds are wrong. Another option is to see if running the transaction without transaction simulation to see if you can get a more verbose error.

Comment: @HenryE I read all of the similary questions and answers but I checked mut, seeds.. also transaction log..

Comment: The next step would be to figure out what specific account is causing the error. Once you know exactly what account is causing the `unauthorized signer or writable account` error, then you can probably narrow down what the issue is better